# What is $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q (2^{1/3})}/\mathbb{Q})$?

Tags: galois-theory

What is $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q (2^{1/3})}/\mathbb{Q})$?

We implement the fact that every automorphism in the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$ maps every root $\alpha \in K$ of $f(x) \in F[x]$ to a root $\sigma(\alpha) \in K$ of $f(x) \in F[x]$ and examine the roots of the polynomial $q(x) = x^3-2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x].$ We note that the roots of $q(x)$ are $2^{1/3}, e^{2 \pi i/3}2^{1/3},e^{4 \pi i/3}2^{1/3}$ and that $e^{2 \pi i/3}2^{1/3},e^{4 \pi i/3}2^{1/3}$ are not contained in the field $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}).$ Since every $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})/\mathbb{Q})$ maps roots to roots, it follows that $\sigma(2^{1/3}) = 2^{1/3}.$ Hence $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q (2^{1/3})}/\mathbb{Q}) = \{\operatorname{id}\}.$

> How does this prove that the identity map is the only automorphism that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$? I understand why $\sigma$ must map $2^{1/3}$ to $2^{1/3}$ but am having trouble going the extra step $\sigma(2^{1/3}) = 2^{1/3} \Longrightarrow \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q (2^{1/3})}/\mathbb{Q}) = \{\operatorname{id}\}.$

Edit: $\sigma(2^{1/3})^3 = \sigma((2^{1/3})^3) = \sigma(2) = 2 \Longrightarrow \sigma(2^{1/3})^3-2=0$ so $\sigma(2^{1/3})$ is a cube root of $2$ lying in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}).$

Comment: Your proof seems fine.

Comment: The extension is not Galois!

Comment: I'd write $\rm Aut$ instead of $\rm Gal$.

Comment: @mich95 But isn't the extension normal since $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ is a splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}?$

Comment: @user167857: No, it's not the splitting field of $x^3-2$. The other roots of $x^3-2$ are
$$\left(\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\sqrt[3]{2},\qquad \left(\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\sqrt[3]{2}$$
which obviously aren't in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Oh right, the splitting field of $x^3-2$ would be $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3},e^{2 \pi i/3})$

Comment: All: There is probably some variation in definitions. At least my Holy Tome of Algebra (Jacobson BA I-II) defines $\operatorname{Gal} E/F$ for all finite extensions of fields, and makes no distinction between $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(E/F)$. In other words, to him using the notation $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$ does not imply that the extension $E/F$ is Galois. Be aware of such variations in ntation and please don't jump on each others case there. You're doing fine, but I've seen such exchanges earlier.